# What type of thermodynamic system is the universe?

Tags: thermodynamics, universe, multiverse

I was studying thermodynamics and came across a thought that **Which type of system is the universe?**

- Is it closed,open, or adiabatic(isolated)?
- Is it even a system ?
- Can it ever be a system?
- Assuming the multiverse theory(or theories) true
  can the multiverse be a system ?
- Can those universes in the mutiverse interact?

Sorry for the long list of questions.

Comment: To reopen this question (v1) consider to mention within which multiverse theory  this question is asked, preferably supported by references.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is much consensus on this question, but here are my thoughts...

The term "universe" can mean different things.  Does it refer to the entire spacetime manifold within which we live?  Or just to the region which could have a causal impact on us at some point in the future?  There is a particle horizon which defines the boundary of what could have influenced us on Earth in the present.  And an event horizon which defines the boundary of what we could influence from Earth in the future.  There are also other possible definitions.  Perhaps we should also include the entire region that could be influenced by anything in the past that we can observe today?  Or should we just arbitrarily pick some "causal patch" which includes Earth?  These ambiguities show up whether or not our universe is also embedded in a larger multiverse where new spacetime regions might be bubbling out of the background spacetime via quantum tunneling.

If the causal patch approach is taken, where we choose a causal diamond that includes Earth, it's conjectured that the total number of states in the universe is finite due to the holographic principle.  If that's true, then I think it's safe to say the universe is a closed thermodynamic system in the traditional sense.  It contains a finite number of degrees of freedom which can only interact with each other, and it's isolated from anything outside of it.  (Aside from quantum entanglement, which as I understand it is already taken care of by replacing the zero temperature of an asymptotically-Minkowski vacuum with the non-zero temperature of an asymptotically-deSitter vacuum.)

If any of the other subsets of the spacetime manifold we live in is chosen as a definition of the universe (most of those corresponding or related to what would usually be called the "observable universe" then I think it makes more sense to call it an open system. It also probably refers to a finite number of states (assuming the holographic principle and other assumptions are correct) but they can interact with things outside of that subset even though this doesn't affect us directly.

If the first approach is taken, and the universe means the entire spacetime manifold we find ourselves in... then a big question remains as to whether it's finite or infinite.  If it's finite, then it's a closed system.  If it's infinite, then perhaps it doesn't fit into either of the traditional categories, as both were originally intended to refer to a finite system.  The significance of something being a closed system is that the aggregate of any locally conserved quantity ends up also being conserved globally (since nothing can get in or out).  For example, if energy is locally conserved in a closed system then the total energy of the system always remains the same.  However, if the universe is infinite, then all of these global aggregates also become infinite.  So it doesn't seem particularly useful to ask the question of whether they are conserved or not:  they were infinite before and they will remain infinite in the future.  Is one infinity the same as another?  That's not always a well-defined question, so whether we call it closed or open doesn't seem to have much significance in the infinite case.